# JSR 303 - Name of the annotated field in the custom validator

Tags: spring, bean-validation, jsr

I have a question about  custom annotations. More precisely, do I have access to the name of the annotated field inside the custom validator ?
If yes, how do I access this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can access path via following exp

```
((ConstraintValidatorContextImpl) context).getConstraintViolationCreationContexts().get(0).getPath()
```

Comment: This solution doesn't appear to work anymore with hibernate.validator 7.0.1.Final.  Can't figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access the name of the validated element from within a constraint validator. It is exposed by the resulting constraint violation, though (via `getPropertyPath()`).

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate implementation, You can get it using reflection ConstraintValidatorContext.basePath.currentLeafNode.name